# Enhanced Vlookup Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am looking for an excel formula that I can use to automatically fill E2 in the screenshot below. The intention is to find Marc's age from column B, ie E2 should be 20. Any ideas please? I have tried Match, VLookup and a number of other functions with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Lisa, what do you want to fill E2 with? What is the intention?

Comment: How is `Mark` related to column A?

Comment: Lisa, are you open to using VBA for this? There is no direct way to do what you are looking for. You can either put hidden cells that contain the names separated and search this way as a suggestion. VBA would be much cleaner though. Why can't the data be entered in a better way?

Comment: I assume she wants it to do a FIND in each cell beneath column A and report back the age. Seems kind of silly to lump the names together in one cell to me

Comment: @duDE I have updated the question.

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanks for the hint, I have updated the question

Comment: @EricF The screenshot in the question is provided based on dummy data. In reality, large raw data comes in this format from an external feed that we can't manipulate (so having the space seperated entries is inevitable). I am open for using VBA for this.

Comment: I left a VBA answer below. If it helps let me know

Answer (score 2):

This almost works:

```
{=INDEX(B$2:B$3, MATCH(1, (SEARCH(D2, A$2:A$3)>0)*1, 0), 1)}
```

That is, search for D2 in each cell of the A range, returning 1 for each cell where it's found, match on 1 exactly to return the successful rows, then index into the B range using the row returned, and get the age from the first column in that range. This assumes the match will only return one row. Use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to get the {} indicating array mode.

Since the name we're looking for could be a prefix of another name, we should look for a word break (space or end of string) len(name) characters after the location where it was found:

```
{=INDEX(B$2:B$3,
        MATCH(0,
              LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A$2:A$3,LEN(D2)+SEARCH(D2,A$2:A$3),1),
                             " ",
                             "")),
              0),
        1)}
```

We should look for a word break at the *beginning* too:

```
{=INDEX(B$2:B$3,MATCH(0,
   LEN(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(MID(A$2:A$3,SEARCH(D2,A$2:A$3)-1,1)," ")," ",""))+
   LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A$2:A$3,LEN(D2)+SEARCH(D2,A$2:A$3),1),       " ","")),
   0),1)}
```

Comment: @lisa17 does this answer the question?

Comment: almost! The problem with this solution is that when somebody's name is (for example) "Johnson", his age would be be confused with someone who's name is "John". Thoughts?

Comment: good catch. without regular expressions, I suspect the answer will get *much* longer, but let me think about it...

Comment: While checking for a word boundary at the beginning and end of the name, I noticed that the match is case-insensitive. Hopefully that matches your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a VBA answer as well. I have set up a sample like yours:

[image]

Using the following macro I wrote:

```
Public Sub do_stuff_and_things()

Dim i As Integer
Dim name_to_find As String
Dim age As String

name_to_find = Range("'Sheet1'!D2").Value


age = "not found"

i = 2

Do Until i = Range("'Sheet1'!A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

 If InStr(Range("'Sheet1'!A" & i).Value, name_to_find) Then
 age = Range("'Sheet1'!B" & i).Value
 Exit Do
 End If

 i = i + 1
Loop


Range("'Sheet1'!E2").Value = age
End Sub
```

It simply uses the InStr function to see if the field contains your search value. Of course this requires the name to be typed exactly how it is in the search column.

Hope this helps.

If you need any help implementing this, definitely let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use vlookup with wildcards:

=VLOOKUP("*" & D2 & "*",$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE)

Where D2 is the cell you would like to lookup (which can also be hardcoded as "Marc"), $A$2:$B$3 is your range, which contains $ in front of each column and row reference, which will make the range static, because you probably do not want your range to change if you are dragging this formula down a column.

2 is the column index you would like to retrieve within your range and false represents that this is an approximation, which when used in conjunction with your wild card *, will lookup any value with Marc in it. xyzMarc123 will return a value.

Comment: This needs clarification.

Comment: Thanks, edited the answer, please let me know if you require more details.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
=VLOOKUP("*?", IFERROR( IF( SEARCH(C2, A2:A3), A2:B3, 0), ""), 2, FALSE)
```

and uses only functions and capabilities available then.

The only oddness is in the lookup value for the `VLOOKUP()`:  `"*?"`. I can never, ever, including here, get lookups to use a bare `*` successfully. If there is a preceding or succeeding character in the string (say, `a*` or `*a`) lookups are always happy to do so, but never the bare asterisk.

I'd say also I find it odd that EVERY help site I've ever seen on the subject... somehow... carefully does not use the bare asterisk in their examples. Except, on the nice side, I'll say maybe they none of them ever imagine a possible use for such, or, on the less so nice side, since they all seem to do the same example set, or an abbreviated one that does not stray from the larger set, I'm really only ever seeing a single help explanation, likely written by whoever writes the first "Hey guys..." to the world of MVP's.

In any case, works like a charm once you add something to the bare asterisk, hence the `?` I add to it making a seemingly identical lookup, but one that works vs. one that does not.

Didn't try more than this one approach though. Nowadays (2022), maybe something like `FILTER()` might be more elegant, though maybe with as much real estate taken up in the formula editor. It would definitely have the advantage of being able to handle there being more than one instance of the lookup value, and therefore allow a more involved look at the data.