# Excel lookup by cell value in another broad cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two different excel tables. one table column contains first name of employee and another table contains multiple first names in one cell and their other values. 
for Example.

**first table**

John
Paul
Peter
Akash
Sam

**Second Table**

Shea,John,Akash
Akash,Peter,Paul
Peter,John,Sam

Now I want to look up by first name on second table and return Yes or No.

Comment: You could take a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/819316/enhanced-vlookup-excel-formula/823187#823187 It is a little different but very similar to what you are asking. Just have it return "Yes" or "No" instead of the age.

Comment: Are the first names in the first table in different cells? You'd like to confirm whether the names in the 1st table appear anywhere in the 2nd table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I understand your question correctly. I'll assume that:

- The first table contains one name per cell
- The second table always uses "," as a separator
- You want to check if the first name of each line in the second table is in the first table (return TRUE) or nor (return FALSE).

If that's the case, this should do it: `=NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(B1;SEARCH(",";B1)-1);$A$1:$A$5;1;FALSE)))`

Explained inside-out:

- First I look for the "," (`SEARCH` gives me the position of the first ",").
- Then I take the string left of it (`LEFT`).
- I lookup that string (`LOOKUP`)  in a table and require that is matches exactly (the last `FALSE` argument).
- If it fails, it returns an error, so we'll check for that (`ERROR` return TRUE if the `LOOKUP` results an error).
- We really want to know if it is found instead that it's an error, so I go from TRUE to FALSE and vice versa using `NOT`.

With some "proof":
[image: Lookup partial string in Excel]